# LINQ - ToString("N2") fails without exception?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

The LINQ Query below works fine without the `.ToString("N2")` part. It also works fine using `.ToString()`. When adding the `("N2")` instead of `()` it then returns nothing without raising any exceptions. Why?

Workaround question: When printing the `FundFee` numbers without formatting they are printed as 9.00000000e-3. This only happens in LINQ queries, the `CurrentCulture` is `en-US`. Any way to change this to non e-notation? Then one workaround could be to use `.ToString().SubString(0,4)` which would work since all numbers are between 0 and 1.

Any other improvement ideas are welcome too:)

```
List<FundStairItem> listFunds = (from fundInfoISIN in amdw.FundsInfos.Where(f => f.Type == 1)
                                 from fundInfoName in amdw.FundsInfos.Where(f =>f.Type == 2)
                                 from fundFee in amdw.FundFees
                                 from securities in amdw.Securities                                                 
                                 where securities.ISIN == fundInfoISIN.Value && fundInfoISIN.Value != null && fundInfoISIN.PortfolioId == fundInfoName.PortfolioId && fundFee.ISIN == securities.ISIN
                                            select new FundStairItem
                                            {
                                                Key = fundInfoISIN.Id,
                                                Name = (fundInfoName.Value != "" && fundInfoISIN.Value != "") ? fundInfoName.Value 
                                                    + " " + fundFee.Class.Trim() + " ( Fee: " + (fundFee.Fee*100).ToString("N2") + "% , ISIN:" +fundInfoISIN.Value +")" : securities.Name
                                            }).GroupBy(p=>p.Key).Select(g=>g.First()).ToList();
```

**Edit (added info from comment):**

Adding this before the query: `amdw.Log = Console.Out` gives the output: *A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll in the console.*

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: That's the thing, no exception. Could it be a bug in LINQ or is that out of the question?

Comment: What about String.Formatting the `Name` expression?

Comment: FundInfoName.Value is a string, so the Name expression evaluates to a string already. And yes there is a ToString method, look again:)

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to mix Linq query syntax and method syntax. It makes code hard to read. Chose the one you like most and stick with it!

Comment: I don't get the downvotes here. At the same time it would be useful if you could work this into a small sample that demonstrates the problem. Try to remove any nonessentials.

Comment: Whats the type of fundFee.Fee? Decimal, double? Also this is just a plain LINQ query right, you're not using LINQ to SQL or anything like that?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I wasn't sure how to do the LINQ Query syntax for the groupby and select in this case. I'll see I can figure it out and edit.

Comment: @AVD: t wouldn't compile if Fee was nullable.

Comment: The amdw object is derived from System.Data.Linq.DataContext and works towards an SQL database. The type of the Fee is non-nullable. (And the corresponding database column doesn't allow nulls).

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thanks, I'll try to work it into a smaller query and see if the issue remains.

Comment: If it's LINQ to SQL then maybe its something to do with the translation to SQL. Can you check what the actual query being run is?

Comment: Adding this before the query: amdw.Log = Console.Out gives the output: A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll
in the console.

Comment: What happens if you replace `(fundFee.Fee*100).ToString("N2")` with `((double)(fundFee.Fee*100)).ToString("N2")`?

Comment: Same result. I didn't get this resolved, I ended up not printing the Fee in this particular list.

Comment: Have you tried `(fundInfoName.Value != "" && fundInfoISIN.Value != "") ? string.Format("{0} {1} Fee: {2:0.00%} , ISIN:{3})", fundInfoName.Value, fundFee.Class.Trim(), fundFee.Fee, fundInfoISIN.Value) : securities.Name`? It's a little more readable and might have different behavior.

Comment: That indeed has different behaviour, it works perfectly. Format obviously doesn't use ToString. If you put it as a post I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ to SQL can't translate format strings to T-SQL.

Instead of relying on SQL Server to format the string, fetch all the data you need into memory and project the data to the correct format from there.

A simple, fictional example:

```
// Don't - LtS tries to translate format string to T-SQL
var formattedFundFeess = from fund in Context.Funds
                         select fund.Fee.ToString("N2");

// Do - fetch your fees into memory and let .NET do the format
var fundFeesInMemory = (from fund in Context.Funds
                        select fund.Fee).ToList();

var formattedFundFees = from fundFee in fundFeesInMemory 
                        select fundFee.ToString("N2");
```

Answer (score -1):

Im connecting to MySQL. It fail when Im using .ToString("N2"), hence I change the decimal places first before proceed to change to string as below:

( Math.Round(fundFee.Fee*100,2) ).ToString()

Comment: See the accepted answer. The problem is SQL translation, not the formatting method itself. This `Math.Round` isn't supported either. Also, please always add some explanation when posting code. Code-only answers are likely to be deleted by reviewers because they have little educational value.